# Let $G$ be a group, let $A$, $B$ be subgroups of $G$ of finite indices : $[G : A],[G:B]$ are finite. Show that $[A:A \cap B] \leq [G:B]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

For the above question, i want to know how to do it without using group actions, i can do the question if the subgroups are finite, which is merely invoking the theorem : $|HK| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|}$ , however, A,B may be infinite.

Comment: This is in Hungerford's graduate algebra book, Chapter 1, Section 4, Proposition 8, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1873474/if-gk-is-finite-then-hh-cap-k-gk-iff-g-hk-hungerford-propo?rq=1), first part.

Answer (score 0):

$[A:A\cap B]$ is the number of (left) cosets of $A\cap B$ in $A$.

Given a coset $a(B\cap A)$ in $A$, then $(aB) \cap A = a(B\cap A)$. Together with the fact that cosets are disjoint, this means that every coset of $B\cap A$ in $A$ is contained in exactly one coset of $B$ in $G$.